# webscraping different websites for a price tracker in Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner at Python and have started web-scraping in Python. At the moment I am trying to build a price tracker for online stores like Amazon. I am able to scrape text such as the price and name of the product from Amazon with BeautifulSoup and requests and after gathering this data, I can compare the price to a threshold price set by the user. If the price is lower than the threshold price, the webscraper will send an email to notify me. I have a list of other online stores/websites that I would like to use my price tracker for such as Footlocker. Since each website has a different html structure, is there a way to code a simple BeautifulSoup webscraper that allows the user to choose which website to scrape from a set list of websites? Do I have to write one for each specific website?. I used an input for the URL so the user has to copy paste the URL into the shell then the webscraper will scrape from the amazon page.

Thank you for reading this far and any other feedback would be greatly appreciated!!!

This is my code so far without the emails for sending the emails and my user agent

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib


URL = input('What Amazon product would you like to check the price of(View price)(please use URL)? ')

threshold = input('What is the threshold amount of the product? ')
threshold = float(threshold)

def check_price():    
    headers = {"User-Agent": }
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()

    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    converted_price = float(price[1:])

    if (converted_price < threshold):
        send_email()
        print(title.strip())
        print(converted_price)
    else:
        print(f'The price of your product has not fallen below ${threshold}')
        print(f'The current price of the {title.strip()} is {converted_price}')


def send_email():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()

    server.login('', '')

    subject = f'The price of your product has fallen'
    body = f'Check the amazon link - {URL}'

    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

    server.sendmail(
        '',
        '',
        msg
    )
    print('The email has been sent')

    server.quit

check_price()
```

Comment: I would expect you would need to scrape per site.   BS is flexible, however there each website will have very differently structured HTML.  Each structure will need some code to extract the content you want

Comment: I am facing the same problem since each website has a different HTML structure, how would a general scraper scrape different structures

Comment: @flow_me_over, how would a general scaper be able to scrape the different structures?? And is it possible to scrape the different structures without parent and child classes??

Answer (score 1):

Every site will have its own specifics. You could build a general Class for your scraping, that covers all similar tasks such as sending email etc.
Then for each website, make a childclass and override the website specific functions.

Comment: Thank you @flow_me_over, Just wondering, to override the website specific functions, would I just have to define the same method in child class that was in the parent/base class? Also if I implemented this into my code, is there any possible way to make the web scraper price track two different chosen websites at the same time with one code?

Comment: Your first question: yes. It can be entirely empty in parent class if you wish. Then in child class, use the same name. As for your second question: I think you would have to look into multithreading. Or write a loop that scrapes one website after the other